Handeling notifications from browser

I have an application where after creating the account I will get a notification from the browser saying "UserName" is created and I need to click on it. How to handle it using selenium.
I tried to resolve it but I'm unable to.

You have to write to use Javascript code to access Notification. Go through below article for the same https://applitools.com/resources/videos/browser-notifications-selenium-java/
